# Yetter-Drinfeld modules for Hopf monads

Tags: ct.category-theory, hopf-algebras, monoidal-categories, monads, braided-tensor-categories

**1. Context.**
*1.1. Classical Yetter-Drinfeld modules.*
Let $H$ a bialgebra in a braided monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$. A *left-right Yetter-Drinfeld module* over $H$ is a triple $(V,\rho,\Delta)$ consisting of a left $H$-module $(V,\rho)$ and a right $H$-comodule $(V,\Delta)$ satisfying the [Yetter-Drinfeld condition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yetter-Drinfeld+module#compatibility_for_leftright_yd_modules). Morphisms of left-right Yetter-Drinfeld modules are morphisms of left modules and right comodules. The category ${}_H{\mathcal{YD}^H}$ of left-right Yetter-Drinfeld modules over $H$ can be given the structure of a braided monoidal category such that the forgetful functor to $\mathcal{C}$ is a monoidal equivalence. If $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of $k$-vector spaces and $H$ is a finite-dimensional Hopf algebra, then there are braided monoidal equivalences
$${}_H{\mathcal{YD}^H}\cong \mathcal{Z}(H\text{-mod})\cong D(H)\text{-mod},$$ where $\mathcal{Z}(H\text{-mod})$ denotes the Drinfeld center of the category of left $H$-modules and $D(H)$ is the Drinfeld double of $H$. In other words, the category of (left-right) Yetter-Drinfeld modules realizes the braided monoidal category $\mathcal{Z}(H\text{-mod})$ directly in terms of the Hopf algebra $H$.

*1.2. Hopf monads.*
Bruguières' and Virelizier's [Hopf monads](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1920.pdf) generalize Hopf algebras to the non-braided setting. Given a centralizable Hopf monad $T$ on a rigid monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$, one can introduce its double Hopf monad $D_T$ (see [Section 6.2.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.2443.pdf)) and then find a braided monoidal isomorphism $\mathcal{Z}(T\mathcal{-C})\cong D_T\mathcal{-C}$, where $\mathcal{Z}(T\mathcal{-C})$ denotes the Drinfeld center of the category of modules over the monad $T$ and $D_T\mathcal{-C}$ is the category of modules over the monad $D_T$. Hopf modules also straight-forwardly generalize to the Hopf monad setting; see the [2006 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604180.pdf) by Bruguières and Virelizier.

**2. Question.**
Is there a analogous notion of Yetter-Drinfeld module in the setting of Hopf monads? Even less precisely: Can the braided monoidal category $\mathcal{Z}(T\mathcal{-C})$ be realized directly in terms of the Hopf monad $T$?